# Where to place logic for loading initial server data in React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using React-Redux to build an application.

To load initial data for a React smart component, I need to dispatch a *Redux* action where the server data requests will happen.

I've tried dispatching the action in constructor (ES6 implementation), `componentWillMount`, and `componenetDidMount`. They all worked.

---

### My question is:

is there a recommended place in the React smart component that the action should be dispatched.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**: [Dan Abramov recently stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41612993/2762747)

> In future versions of React we expect that componentWillMount will fire more than once in some cases, so you should use componentDidMount for network requests.

---

In `componentDidMount`

Read [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html).

> **Fetch data in componentDidMount**. When the response arrives, store the data in state, triggering a render to update your UI.
>
> When fetching data asynchronously, **use componentWillUnmount to cancel any outstanding requests** before the component is unmounted.

Documentation is really scarce on "why in `componentDidMount`". I believe `componentWillMount` is not called if you use server-side render, so this could be a reason why `componentDidMount` is preferred.

Comment: Yeah. I've read the doc you mentioned. But trying to understand why in componentDidMount? Since the dispatch action in other places also worked.

Comment: I believe componentDidMount is used for side effects such as async actions or mutating DOM directly, but couldn't find the exact source at the moment.. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is, I believe, to do it in componentDidMount. See [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) for more info.