# How to pass Firebase JSON object as a prop in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-router

I'm trying to pass a Firebase response object from my index.js file into a component as Props, and I can't quite figure out how to pull it off. This is my database query:

```
`var allFlies = firebase.database().ref('flies');
allFlies.on('value', function(snapshot){
   var myObj = snapshot.val()
  })`
```

Which returns a JSON object (and four smaller objects inside of it that I want to be able to use). I'm trying to pass the info in and access it like so:

```
`ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
      <Route path="/basics" component={Basics}></Route>
      <Route path="/flies" component={ ()=> <Flies flyProps={myObj}/> }></Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>, document.getElementById('root'));`
```

I'm not sure how to "export" myObj due to the scope issue.

Comment: To make this work you have to move `ReactDOM.render` function into the callback function where you get `snapshot`. But this is not how usually we fetch data in React. You should move this data fetching part to `componentDidMount` lifecycle method of a component. Read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612200/in-react-js-should-i-make-my-initial-network-request-in-componentwillmount-or-co?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Ok, I decided to move everything to the component as you suggested. Makes sense after reading what you linked to. Thanks!