# Why componentWillMount should not be used?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Firing server call to fetch data in componentWillMount life cycle method a bad practice?

And why it is better to use componentDidMount.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**UPDATE:** componentWillMount will soon be [deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount).

---

To cite [@Dan Abramov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458193/dan-abramov)

> In **future versions of React we expect that componentWillMount will fire more than once** in some cases, so you should use componentDidMount for network requests.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41612993/2762747).

Comment: This is what I read sometime back but never had a justifiable reason on why it will get called multiple times.

Comment: This is a link only answer that does not explain the "why" context of the question. Any of the other responses answer the question better, so this should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry if my question is stupid. If I fetch data in componentWillMount, even if it does not break the component that is rendered for the first time, whether the fetch data function in` componentWillMount` will be called a bit earlier than the fetch data componentDidMount function, resulting in Do we get the data a little faster?

Answer (score 23):

**UPDATE - may / 2018**
There is a new feature for react in a working progress called [async rendering](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html).
As of react `v16.3.2` these methods are not "safe" to use:

- componentWillMount
- componentWillReceiveProps
- componentWillUpdate

you can read more about it in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount).

---

As a general rule [don't use](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) `componentWillMount` at all (if you use the es6 `class` syntax). use the `constructor` method instead.
This life-cycle  method is good for a sync state initialization.
`componentDidMount` in the other hand is good for async state manipulation.

**Why**?
Well, when you do an async request in the `constructor` / `componentWillMount` you do it before `render` gets called, by the time the async operation has finished the `render` method most probably already finished and no point to set the "initial state" at this stage is it?.
I'm not sure this is your case here, but most of the cases that developers wants to initiate state asynchronously in `componentWillMount` is to avoid a second `render` call. but you can't avoid it can you, like mentioned above, `render` will fire anyway before the async operation will finish.
So, the best time to call an async operation is after a `render` has called and the component mounted (you could mount `null` or an empty `<div/>`) and then fetch your data, set the state and make it re-render respectively.

Comment: Correct, explanation with async calls example gives enough reason for not using componentwillmount. Thanks buddy :)

Comment: Sorry if my question is stupid. If I fetch data in componentWillMount, even if it does not break the component that is rendered for the first time, whether the fetch data function in` componentWillMount` will be called a bit earlier than the fetch data componentDidMount function, resulting in Do we get the data a little faster?

Comment: @DuyHưngAndrogyneTenor 
No, because it doesn't matter when you get the data, what matters is when can you do something with it. The fact that the data is being handled in an async operation, it will only run after ALL sync work is done. So i doubt there's a difference.

Comment: @Sagivb.g: Yea, thank so much, so, all process from constructor, mounting to end of rendering are synchronus actions, right? And those will go to callstack before async actions?

Comment: @DuyHưngAndrogyneTenor 
All user's code (not react's code like `setState` for example) is sync. So yeah, our code will run to completion before async code. Unless of course when we use async API's like setTimeout promise etc..

Answer (score 9):

`componentDidMount` is the best place to put calls to fetch data, for two reasons:

1. Using `componentDidMount` makes it clear that data won’t be loaded until after the initial render. You need to setup initial state properly, so you don’t get `undefined` state that causes errors.
2. If you need to render your app on the server, `componentWillMount` will be called twice(on the server and again on the client), which is probably not what you want. Putting the data loading code in `componentDidMount` will ensure that data is only fetched from the client. Generally, you should not add side effects to `componentWillMount`.

Comment: I want to show loader before component shows up

Answer (score 3):

**Component Mounting life cycle is**

- constructor()
- componentWillMount() /UNSAFE_componentWillMount()(react 16)
- render()
- componentDidMount()

**Constructor** and **componentWillMount** both call before render() call which is responsible for page rendering.

Here State initialized is done in Constructor and api are called in componentDidMount because of async calls.

**ComponentWillMount was good to initialized state before ES6** when constructor was not there. But now ComponentWillMount is good for nothing and react team is thinking it after react 17.

**In addition** to above, react have moved to react [fiber architecture](https://github.com/acdlite/react-fiber-architecture), to avoid unnecessary re-rendering and improve performance, react has decided to move away from componentWillMount, componentWillReciveProps and componentWillUpdate methods.

Comment: it's not answering why componentWillMount is unsafe and is not used for data fetching.

Comment: This is the official statement of React. They introduced it for good reason and now because of ES6 it is no longer needed so React team itself declare it as unsafe. and recommends use of constructor() over  componentWillMount().

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand it, one of the biggest reasons has to do with **setting up the right expectations for the developers** reading the code.

If we use `componentWillMount` it's tempting to think that the fetch have time to happen, then the component "did" mount, and *then* the first render will happen. But that it not the case. If we do an async call (like an API call with Promises), the component will actually run `render` before the fetch can return and set the component state (or change the Redux state, or what ever).

If we instead use `componentDidMount`, then it's clear that the component will render at least once before you get back any data (because the component already *did* mount). So, by extension, it's also clear that we have to handle the initial state in a way so that the component doesn't break on the first ("empty") render.