# the console shows that the arrays in the state have been populated but I can't access the object[0]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, render

[On my code you can see functions that populate the state being called on component will mount. I then log the state on the render and this is what I see on the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssgBQ.png)

[As you can see the log will show me that the arrays in the state have been populated albeit a bit late, but I cannot log the first object in the arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiyDf.png)

I have a feeling this has something to do with the react render cycle but I can't figure out what. Thanks a lot for taking the time to view my question.

Comment: Have you tried this with componentDidMount, instead of componentWillMount? I believe componentWillMount is being deprecated. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46043832/why-componentwillmount-should-not-be-used

Comment: its all because of when the render was called. just for testing. use a `setTimeout` and give a delay of 200-500ms and see what is the result

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for checking my code I have tried your suggestions but not much has changed at all, any other suggestions??

Comment: @hannadrehman you want me to put a setTimeout on the render() function??

Comment: Please add code as text, not an image of code. Are `fetchAllArtists`/`fetchAllEvents` asynchronous? The console does not reflect the state of the time you were logging those things. Instead it is only evaluated when you expand it (see the blue icon).

Comment: Hey @str here's what the fetchAllArtists looks like on another function:

`const fetchAllArtists = (array) => {
    firebaseArtists.once("value")
        .then((snapshot) => {
            const artists = firebaseLooper(snapshot);
            array.push(...artists);
        })
}`

Sorry if it looks terrible, I'm not sure how to post code on here.

As you can see the function takes in the array and populates it from the data in the firebase database. 

My problem is that the render function happens before the state is populated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: for testing yes. you can put it in render. just see weather delayed call has the values

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried initializing your state in the class `constructor` method?  This way, the class's state will be initialized with the default values before the first attempt to render:

```
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            allEvents: [],
            allArtists: []
        };
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

Also, I agree with George Chanturidze's comment about using the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method instead of `componentWillMount`.

**UPDATE: Added a snippet in an unsuccessful attempt to reproduce the issue**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    concatArray: [],
    es6Array: [],
    pushArray: []
  };

  componentWillMount = () => {
    var concat = this.state.concatArray.concat({
      name: "A_concat",
      value: 1
    }).concat({
      name: "B_concat",
      value: 2
    });
    this.state.pushArray.push({
      name: "C_push",
      value: 3
    });
    this.state.pushArray.push({
      name: "D_push",
      value: 4
    });
    this.setState({
      concatArray: concat,
      es6Array: { ...this.state.es6Array,
        ...[{
          name: "E_es6",
          value: 5
        }, {
          name: "F_es6",
          value: 7
        }]
      }
    });
  };

  render = () => {
    console.clear();
    console.log(this.state);
    console.log(this.state.concatArray);
    console.log(this.state.concatArray[0]);
    console.log(this.state.pushArray);
    console.log(this.state.pushArray[0]);
    console.log(this.state.es6Array);
    console.log(this.state.es6Array[0]);
    return null;
  };
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for checking my code I have tried your suggestions but not much has changed at all, any other suggestions??

Comment: Hi, @RuairidhGrass.  I added a snippet to my answer in an effort to reproduce the "undefined" result when indexing for the fist array item with [0].  I tried to mirror the relevant pieces of your code, such as initializing state outside of using the class constructor and retaining componentWillMount.  In my case, all three of my console.log statements appear to work as expected, including logging the state, logging the whole array, and logging the first array item.  Are you able to provide a snippet that reproduces the issue or maybe include more of your code that might be applicable?

Comment: Hi @Kevin I really appreciate your efforts! I think the problem may lie in my `fetchAllArtists(array)` method. It's a method that fetches data from a firebase database and then populates the array with that data. The function lives in a separate js file in an effort to keep my code dry. This is what said function looks like:

`const fetchAllArtists = (array) => {
    firebaseArtists.once("value")
        .then((snapshot) => {
            const artists = firebaseLooper(snapshot);
            array.push(...artists);
        })
}`

Comment: @RuairidhGrass I am still failing to duplicate the "undefined" exactly, but I know that you should avoid mutating the array by way of using the Array.push() method and instead use this.setState to pass the new arrays to your respective state properties.  This is better explained on some of the top answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435334/correct-way-to-push-into-state-array.  I updated my example to include how this would be handled for using the Array.concat() method as well as the ES6 syntax.  I also included using Array.push() in a failed attempt to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hey @kevin I've posted an answer bellow with some images of it working. thanks