# i'm not sure why the debugger line doesn't get hit in this simple example

Tags: node.js

Why doesn't the debugger line get hit? Please let me know how to modify the code so it does get hit.

```
async _store_token(tok){  // tried this line with and without 'async', just to see
      debugger;     // THIS LINE DOESN'T GET CAUGHT BY DEBUGGER
  }

  componentWillMount(){

     //debugger;

     axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: BASE_URL + '/users/login',
  data: {
      email: "email1@mail.com",
    password: "passpass"
  }
})
  .then(async function (res) {
    debugger;                       // CODE IS FINE AT THIS DEBUG STATEMENT
    _store_token(res.token);  // TRIED TO USE 'this._store_token(res.token);'
                               // but it didn't work either



})
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `scope` of `this` keyword. May be you want to use arrow method functionality.

example

```
then(async res => {})
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tired it with the 'this' keyword and without it. Both didn't work

Comment: it worked with both the 'this' keywords and the arrow function. How would I get it to work if i wasn't using the arrow function?

Comment: You need to pass 'this' to any variable on function level scope and then you can use it inside anonymous function without using arrow method. like   `componentWillMount() {
    //debugger;
    const self = this;
    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: BASE_URL + '/users/login',
    }).then(async function(res) {
      self._store_token().bind();
    });
  }`

Comment: Also I would suggest use `componentDidMount` the `componentWillMount`. Here is the one link I found quickly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46043832/why-componentwillmount-should-not-be-used