# How to display an image with <img> from Mongoose using React front-end

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express, mongoose

Ultimate goal: have the user upload pictures (less than 16mb so no need to worry about Grid FS), have that picture stored in my database which is Mongodb through Mongoose, and display the picture on the screen using the  attribute.

To upload files I use Multer and add it to the database as follows:

```
newItem.picture.data = Buffer(fs.readFileSync(req.file.path), 'base64');
newItem.picture.contentType = 'image/png';
```

And it seems to be successfully added to the mongodb. Looks something like this:
[how the image appears on mongodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrh6x.png)

I'm able to send a get request from my front-end and, when I console.log it, this is what I'm getting: [Data after being retreived from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ow2L.png). The question now is, how can I add it to an  attribute and show the image on the screen. Thanks!

Edit: question has been marked as too broad by the moderators. Fair enough, I wasn't too sure how to approach it. Since I was able to solve it, this is what my front-end looks like.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const PATH = "http://localhost:8080/apii/items/getitems";
    axios.get(PATH)
    .then(res => {            
        let picture64Bit = res.data[0].data.data
        picture64Bit = new Buffer(x, 'binary').toString('base64');
        this.setState({picture: picture64Bit})
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

The key here is that, 1) res.data[0].data.data is equal to that random list of numbers. I take that convert it back to base64, so it appears exactly as it did in the first picture above from mongodb. Then, displaying it inline in an img attribute is very easy:

```
<img src = {`data:image/png;base64,${this.state.picture}`} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple libraries you could use, but I will arbitrarily select `Axios` for a demonstration. It sounds good if the images are already in Mongo DB.

Your objective is to get photos from the server to the client, so you need a function to get them on demand. You could also investigate `fetch` or `request`.

Axios: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

In React, try something like this

```
  async getPhotos() {
    const res = await Axios.get('/photos')
    console.log('RESPONSE', res)

    const photos = res.data
    console.log('IMAGES', photos)

    this.setState({ photos })
  }
```

Here is a more complete example

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios'

class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) { // super props allows props to be available 
    super(props)       // inside the constructor
    this.state = {
      photos : [],     // Initialize empty list to assert existence as Array type
                       // and because we will retrieve a list of jpegs
      error: '',       // Initialize empty error display
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPhotos()   // Do network calls in componentDidMount
  }

  async getPhotos() {
    try {
      const res = await Axios.get('/photos')
      console.log('RESPONSE', res)

      const photos = res.data
      console.log('IMAGES', photos)

      this.setState({ photos, error: '' })
    } catch (e) {
      this.setState({ error: `BRUTAL FAILURE: ${e}` })
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (error.length) {
      return (
        <div>{this.state.error}</div>
      )
    }
    if (!photos.length) {
      return (
        <div>No photos yet</div>
      )
    }
    // Assuming shape { id: 0, caption: 'Cats again', src: 'http://www.com/win.jpg' }
    // Make sure to include key prop when using map (for state management)
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.photos.map(photo => (
          <li key={photo.id} style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
            <span>{photo.caption}</span>
            <img src={photo.src}
            <div
              className="overlay"
              style={{
                position: 'absolute'
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
              }}
            />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

**Citation**: [In React.js should I make my initial network request in componentWillMount or componentDidMount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612200/in-react-js-should-i-make-my-initial-network-request-in-componentwillmount-or-co)

If you want to fetch one more photo after, you should try to think immutably and replace the `this.state.photos` Array with a duplicate of itself plus the new image pushed onto the end of the array. We will use the spread operator for this to do a shallow copy on the existing photos Array. This will allow React to diff against the two states and efficiently update for the new entry.

```
const res = await Axios.get('/photo?id=1337')
const photo = res.data

this.setState({
  photos: [...photos, photo]
})
```

**Note**: the secret trick is to avoid ever doing `this.state.photos.push(photo)`. You must place an illegal sign on setting state like that.

In React, try to consider a way you can get an Object or Array. Once you have it in your mind, throw it into a Component's state. As you progress into Redux, you will end up storing items sometimes in the Redux store. That is too complex and unnecessary to describe now. The photos would be available perhaps as `this.props.photos` via the Redux Connect Function.

For most other times, a Component's state field is an excellent place to store anything of interest to a Component.

You can imagine it like a holder at the top of the Component.

Comment: Thanks for the splendid response! I was able to get it to work but I had to do one key thing using Axios. For some reason, it was not sending the pictures from the server in 'base 64' format. It was a lit of random numbers but no letters. So on the front-end, I used a function to convert it to base 64 then displayed it as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395034/how-to-display-image-in-react.
Not sure exactly why this happens since on the database it's clearly base 64 (as seen in the picture) so some clarification would be nice haha.

Comment: Did you get it solved? By reading your new notes there it sounds like you were able to convert it to base64 and successfully display it.

Comment: I was able to get it solved, but I'd just like to understand why the picture changed encoding schemes/format when I pulled it from the db. In mongo, the picture appeared in base64 format, but when I pull it from the db its just numbers (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ow2L.png). If this weird conversion didn't happen, then this whole issue would not have occurred.